# How do you add a counter to a list comprehension?

Tags: python

I'm trying to re-write the following in a list comprehension, but I'm struggling to add the counter in:

```
create_list = []
    counter = 0
    for x in my_list:
        create_list.append(f(x+counter))
        counter += 1
```

I've tried:

`create_list = [f(x+counter) for x in my_list]` but obviously this doesn't increase the counter.

Comment: Are you looking for `enumerate()` ?

Comment: How could I use enumerate() to complete this?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't your counter always be the same as the length `my_list` or more accurately, `create_list`? Or is there some additional logic that is just not in this example?

Answer (score 8):

You could use `enumerate()`:

```
new_list = [f(val+index) for (index, val) in enumerate(my_list)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is definitely not the best way to handle it (I hate having to import stuff!), but it's pretty cool and works:

```
counter = -1

def g(x): # function with side-effect! returns back the value.
    global counter
    counter = counter + 1
    return counter

create_list = [f(x)+g(x)) for x in my_list] #btw you might want to type cast? I don't really know your data sets nor functionality of f, so I'm not sure
```

There are a lot of other ways too such as making a second list based off the `len(my_list)` and then using zip to sort of "parallel" compute, or using two list comprehensions, etc.

Comment: `enumerate()` is a built-in, no imports needed. And `//` is not a comment in Python. And Python has no type casting.

Comment: I didn't even think of enumerate(), and I've been using too many languages at once :")

Comment: and by typecasting, I meant like `str(counter)` but I didn't know what my_list was

Comment: That's using a function to produce a different object type. Typecasting is a different process, where the compiler is told to treat data in memory as a different type in a static language, something a dynamic language like Python doesn't need.